Asynchronous Python: Sleeping Coroutines Blocking Each Other in Scheduler
So I've got an asynchronous scheduling algorithm I'm facing an issue with. In the "dispatcher" method it calcualates the remaining time to sleep before calling a task. However, this seems to be blocking the execution as when I use sleep it just freezes (sleeps) indefinitely. I suspect that coroutines might be blocking each other. How can I structure the sleeping logic within the scheduler to prevent coroutine blocking and ensure timely task execution? Any guidance or suggestions would be appreciated.
Here is the 2 files I'm using:
tests.py: https://pastebin.com/yf44Y2C6
import asyncio
import aiosqlite
import datetime
import json
from scheduling import Scheduler
from constants import DBPath, Schema
 
class App:
    def __init__(self):
        self.db = None
        self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
 
    async def connect(self):
        self.db = await aiosqlite.connect(DBPath, detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES | sqlite3.PARSE_COLNAMES)
        await self.db.executescript(Schema)
        self.scheduler = Scheduler(self)
 
    def on_task_end(self, task):
        print(
            f"\ncall_task - Task ended: \n",
            f"  ID: {task.id}"
            f"  Title: {task.title}\n"
        )
        # TODO: ensure you outline that 'active' is 0 (False)
 
async def test_dispatcher_resume(app):
    print("Starting the scheduler...")
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    app.scheduler.start()
 
    with open('d.json', "r") as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        scheduled = data.get("scheduled", False)
 
    if not scheduled:
        print("\nScheduling task...")
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        await app.scheduler.schedule(
            1,
            "Shopping",
            "You need to buy strawberries and cereal from the supermarket.",
            datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=20),
            1,
            2,
            datetime.datetime.now()
        )
        print("\nTask scheduled!")
 
        data["scheduled"] = True
        with open('d.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(data, f)
 
async def run(app):
    await app.connect()
    await test_dispatcher_resume(app)
 
def main():
    app = App()
    app.loop.run_until_complete(run(app))
 
main()

scheduling.py: https://paste.pythondiscord.com/6TRQ
import asyncio
import datetime
from constants import *


class Task:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.id = data[0]
        self.user_id = data[1]
        self.title = data[2]
        self.description = data[3]
        self.ends = data[4]
        self.priority = PRIORITIES[str(data[5])]  # sets the attribute to the name mapped to the ID
        self.status = STATUSES[str(data[6])]
        self.active = data[7]
        self.timestamp = data[8]


class Scheduler:
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app
        self.db = app.db
        self.loop = app.loop
        self.data_received = asyncio.Event()  # signals when a task is received
        self.currentTask = None
        self.dispatcher_process = None  # task dispatcher background task

    def start(self):
        # create and start the background task
        self.dispatcher_process = self.loop.create_task(self.dispatcher())

    def stop(self):
        if self.dispatcher_process is not None:
            self.dispatcher_process.cancel()  # cancel the background task
    
    def restart(self):
        # stop and start the background task
        self.stop()
        self.start()

    async def get_active_task(self, days):
        # the current time plus teh days to find tasks ending within that range
        future = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=days)
        
        print("\nSearching for any tasks that ended before: ", future)

        query = """
            SELECT * FROM Tasks
            WHERE active = ? AND ends < ?
            ORDER BY ends
            LIMIT 1;
            """
        
        # execute the query
        # True is converted to an integer for sqlite to understand
        cursor = await self.db.execute(query, [int(True), future])
        record = await cursor.fetchone() # fetch the record from the cursor

        # return a new task instance if a record is found
        return Task(record) if record else None

    async def wait_for_active_tasks(self, days):
        task = await self.get_active_task(days=days)  # get an active task
        now = datetime.datetime.now()  # current timestamp
        if task is not None:
            self.data_received.set()  # set the event to indicate data availability
            
            remaining_time = (task.ends - now).total_seconds()
            print(f"\nwait_for_active_tasks - Task found: {task.id}\nEnding in", remaining_time, "seconds")
            return task  # return the task
        else:
            # clear the event and reset the current task
            self.data_received.clear()
            self.currentTask = None
            
            print(f"wait_for_active_tasks - No ended tasks or tasks ending within {days} days found.")
            print("\nWaiting for a task...")
            
            # wait for the event to be set by the scheduler
            await self.data_received.wait()

            # once the event is set, retrieve the task
            return await self.get_active_task(days=days)

    async def call_task(self, task):
        # mark the task as inactive in the database
        query = """
            UPDATE Tasks
            SET active = ?
            WHERE taskID = ?;
            """
        await self.db.execute(query, (int(False), task.id))
        await self.db.commit()  # commit the change
        
        # call the event handler in the user interface
        self.app.on_task_end(task)

    async def dispatcher(self):
        while True:
            # get tasks that end in 7 days or less into the future
            # as they are worth sleeping on
            task = self.currentTask = await self.wait_for_active_tasks(days=7)
            now = datetime.datetime.now()

            if task.ends >= now:
                to_sleep = (task.ends - now).total_seconds()
                print("Task found. Sleeping for", to_sleep, "seconds before calling it...\n")
                await asyncio.sleep(to_sleep)
            
            await self.call_task(task)

    async def schedule(
        self, userID, title, description, ends, priority, status, timestamp
        ):
        # remove timezone information, the database does not handle that
        
        query = """
            INSERT INTO Tasks(userID, title, description, ends, priorityID, statusID, active, timestamp)
            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
            RETURNING *;
            """

        cursor = await self.db.execute(
            query, [userID, title, description, ends, priority, status, int(True), timestamp]
        )
        data = await cursor.fetchone()  # this fetches all the inserted data and primary key
        await self.db.commit()

        # only set the data check if it can be waited on
        if (ends - timestamp).total_seconds() <= (86400 * 7):  # 7 days
            self.data_received.set()

        # check if this task is earlier than our currently run task
        if self.currentTask and ends < self.currentTask.ends:
            # restart the scheduler so this task is executed first as its earlier
            self.restart()
        
        return Task(data)  # return new task object with database record

    async def delete(self, task_id):
        # build the transaction query
        transaction = """
            BEGIN;
            DELETE * FROM Tasks WHERE TaskID = ?;
            DELETE * FROM Comments WHERE TaskID = ?;
            COMMIT;
            """

        await self.db.execute(transaction, [task_id])
        
        # get the count of deleted records
        cursor = await self.db.execute("SELECT changes() AS count")
        result = await cursor.fetch_one()
        if result["count"] == 0:
            # nothing was deleted
            return False

        # if the current task is being deleted
        if self.currentTask:
            if self.currentTask.id == task_id:
            # restart the scheduler
                self.restart()
        
        return True  # task was successfully deleted

I tried putting asyncio.sleep inside a task of its own and awaiting that. But same result.

As a long-time user of asyncio I can absolutely 100% guarantee that an asyncio.sleep call in one Task does not interact with an asyncio.sleep in another Task.  That would break the whole package completely.  No one else can run your program as it depends on your database, and I seriously doubt if anyone is ever going to read your long listing and try to understand it.  At the very least, you need to be more specific about what is wrong: you say that "it" freezes indefinitely but you don't explain what "it" means - is it one Task or the entire program?
